# обработка csv файла на python

Tags: python, csv

обрабатываю файл csv необходимо подсчитать количество посещений на каждой стадии, но вместо этого получаю нулевые значения.
должно получиться как-то так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а получается вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код

```
import csv
funnel_device={}
funnel_month={}
funnel_set={"1_home_page":0, "2_search_page":0, "3_payment_page":0, "4_payment_confirmation_page":0}
with open('C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\click_stream2.csv', mode='r') as csv_file: # открываем файл
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file) # читаем файл
    for  row in csv_reader:
        page=list(row.items())[1][1]
        data=list(row.items())[2][1][:-3]
        device=list(row.items())[3][1]
        if device not in funnel_device.keys():
            funnel_device[device]=funnel_month.copy()
        if data not in funnel_device.keys():
            funnel_device[device][data]=funnel_set.copy()


        if page=="1_home_page":
            funnel_device[device][data][page]+=1
        elif page=="2_search_page":
            funnel_device[device][data][page]+=1
        elif page=="3_payment_page":
            funnel_device[device][data][page]+=1
        else:
            funnel_device[device][data][page]+=1
print(funnel_device)
```

Comment: **1)** вместо тех `if`'ов можно было оставить только `funnel_device[device][data][page] += 1`, там других вариантов нет **2)** оператор `in` и так проверяет по ключам словаря, поэтому можно не писать `.keys()`

Comment: без if не работает проверил

Comment: Быть того не может, у вас там что есть совпадение с `page`, что нет, все-равно значение добавится. Правда, если в `page` будет значение, не совпадающее с ключами из `funnel_set` (откуда данные и копируются), то возникнет исключение, но оно и в текущем коде будет в `else` если `page` будет не `4_payment_confirmation_page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка копипасты в проверке ключа (дважды проверяется `not in funnel_device.keys()`), правильно так:

```
        if device not in funnel_device:
            funnel_device[device] = funnel_month.copy()
        if data not in funnel_device[device]:
            funnel_device[device][data] = funnel_set.copy()
```

Comment: заработало - спасибо!

Comment: @НикитаЗинин, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)